# call fragments when clicking RecyclerView item and show them both in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Since I only changed from buttons to RecyclerView (and it worked just fine with the buttons), I know my java code is working fine, so now I face a problem because clicking a cards in the RecyclerView calls the fragment with the FragmentManager, but not showing it.
Here is my activity.xml code.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".mainSearch"
        android:background="#f2f2f2">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <fragment
        android:name="com.diamcom.blue.StoneCodeFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you have here is having both the recyclerview and the fragment as match_parent for both width and height. A way I think you can do that is by wrapping the containerview which holds the recyclerview and the fragment in a framelayout and making the containerview to be gone when you click on any of the cards in the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

<fragment
    android:name="com.diamcom.blue.StoneCodeFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">
</fragment>

public class mainSearch extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private StoneCodeFragment stoneCodeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_search);

        // Initialize your RecyclerView and adapter here
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(/* ... */);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Initialize your StoneCodeFragment
        stoneCodeFragment = (StoneCodeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_place);

        // Set a click listener for your RecyclerView items
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                // Handle the item click here
                // Show the fragment
                showFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                // Handle long click if needed
            }
        }));
    }

    // Method to show the fragment
    private void showFragment() {
        if (stoneCodeFragment != null) {
            stoneCodeFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```